# Сбивается секундомер после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть обычный секундомер.
Как сделать так что бы после перезагрузки страницы секундомер не сбивался на нули и когда запускать отчет брать из php переменной?

```html
<script>
window.onload = () => {
  StartStop();
}

//объявляем переменные
var base = 60;
var clocktimer, dateObj, dh, dm, ds, ms;
var readout = '';
var h = 1,
  m = 1,
  tm = 1,
  s = 0,
  ts = 0,
  ms = 0,
  init = 0;

//функция для очистки поля
function ClearСlock() {
  clearTimeout(clocktimer);
  h = 1;
  m = 1;
  tm = 1;
  s = 0;
  ts = 0;
  ms = 0;
  init = 0;
  readout = '00:00:00';
  document.MyForm.stopwatch.value = readout;
}

//функция для старта секундомера
function StartTIME() {
  var cdateObj = new Date();
  var t = (cdateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTime()) - (s * 1000);
  if (t > 999) {
    s++;
  }
  if (s >= (m * base)) {
    ts = 0;
    m++;
  } else {
    ts = parseInt((ms / 100) + s);
    if (ts >= base) {
      ts = ts - ((m - 1) * base);
    }
  }
  if (m > (h * base)) {
    tm = 1;
    h++;
  } else {
    tm = parseInt((ms / 100) + m);
    if (tm >= base) {
      tm = tm - ((h - 1) * base);
    }
  }
  ms = Math.round(t / 10);
  if (ms > 99) {
    ms = 0;
  }
  if (ms == 0) {
    ms = '00';
  }
  if (ms > 0 && ms <= 9) {
    ms = '0' + ms;
  }
  if (ts > 0) {
    ds = ts;
    if (ts < 10) {
      ds = '0' + ts;
    }
  } else {
    ds = '00';
  }
  dm = tm - 1;
  if (dm > 0) {
    if (dm < 10) {
      dm = '0' + dm;
    }
  } else {
    dm = '00';
  }
  dh = h - 1;
  if (dh > 0) {
    if (dh < 10) {
      dh = '0' + dh;
    }
  } else {
    dh = '00';
  }
  readout = dh + ':' + dm + ':' + ds;
  document.MyForm.stopwatch.value = readout;
  clocktimer = setTimeout("StartTIME()", 1);
}

//Функция запуска и остановки
function StartStop() {
  if (init == 0) {
    ClearСlock();
    dateObj = new Date();
    StartTIME();
    init = 1;
  } else {
    clearTimeout(clocktimer);
    init = 0;
  }
}
</script>
<form name=MyForm>
  <input name=stopwatch size=10 value="00:00:00.00" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: Сохраняйте dateObj в localStorage (в миллисекундах) и при инициализации восстанавливайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

на каждом тике так

```
localStorage.setItem('time', value);
```

а потом при загрузке старницы так

```
value = +localStorage.getItem(value);
```